# What is the syntax for boolean attributes, e.g. a checked checkbox, in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Sounds like a bit of a silly question, but I am wondering what is the best way of stating that a checkbox is checked/unchecked in HTML.

I have seen many different examples:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox"  />

<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="no" />

<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />
```

Which browsers work with which ones of these, and most importantly, does jQuery figure out which box is checked in all 3?

**Edit:**
The W3C spec seems to imply that just the checked attr being there is correct. Does that mean that checked="false" and checked="no" will still check the box though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

For XHTML you have to use attribute/value matching pairs:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: `checked=""` is also valid.  Additional reading material: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#boolean-attributes

Answer (score 7):

**HTML:**

Any of them should be the right one as they say on [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1). `checked` attribute just has to be set.

As I wrote in Coronatus' comment:

> In fact, it doesn't matter if it's
>   checked, checked="whatever" or
>   checked="checked". It's checking
>   boolean value, so it's either true
>   (set) or false (not set).

**XHTML:**

You have to specify it, so `checked="checked"` is the only valid one. Most of the browsers will probably parse HTML values correct, but you'll have error on your page nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked), the correct one is:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

I use this and jQuery works perfectly with them.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't matter if it's checked, checked="whatever" or checked="checked". It's checking boolean value, so it's either true (set) or false (not set).

Answer (score 2):

A quick test reveals that jQuery equates any value set to being checked.

```
alert( $('input:checked').length );
// Returns 5
```

Even an empty string and the negative values.

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) your first suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the "checked" **property** specifies the status. The value is irrelevant/not needed.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox"  />
```

is my suggestion

Comment: The value does matter - it can only be "checked" (Browsers just error correct for rubbish. Don't depend on error recovery, write error free code instead). If you are writing HTML (as opposed to XHTML) you may (and should) omit the name (and the equals and the quotes) leaving just the value. (Boolean attributes are weird.)

Comment: As you saw from the code on the post I am not saying that the value should not be present. I am just saying that you could write checked="hello" or checked="maybe" and still get the desired result.

Comment: But yes you are right that we should target XHTML and not just HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful using it on chrome, firefox and opera. Chorme seems to have a problem with checkboxes showing up, Firefox is case sensitive with styles and tags, and opera seems to run fine but is slow at updating. Might just be the versions of the browsers being used.

Other than that I believe that it should run `<input type="checkbox" checked />` just fine in all of them. The only difference really is how the individual browsers appear to show the content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

> The W3C spec seems to imply that just the checked attr being there is correct. Does that mean that checked="false" and checked="no" will still check the box though?

Exactly. That's why it's a bad idea to use `checked="true"` and `checked="yes"`, they imply that `checked="false"` and `checked="no"` will not check the box.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 spec**:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**:

Let `boolean` be a boolean attribute of tag `tag`, like `checked` and `<input type="checkbox"`.

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<tag boolean />
<tag boolean="" />
<tag boolean="boolean" />
<tag boolean="BoOlEaN" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<tag boolean="0" />
<tag boolean="1" />
<tag boolean="false" />
<tag boolean="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<tag />
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `boolean="boolean"`, since `<tag boolean>` is invalid XHTML (but valid HTML) and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<tag boolean>` as it is shorter.

Comment: Any idea the though behind this design?  It seems counter intuitive and I can't think of any advantage over just using a boolean value. 

For example, I'm working with a rendering engine (VisualForce/ Salesforce) that doesn't support this notation.

Comment: @NSjonas Nope! :-) maybe because shorter to write?