# How to mark selected options in for the option HTML tag?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using normal select and mutliselect boxes on my site.
should I use `<option selected="selected">` or simply `<option selected>` for selected items ?

Comment: I think it is fine to use either but I would be interested to know if anyone has any detailed reason why to use one over the other. I'm sure if there is a difference it is negligible...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for boolean attributes, e.g. a checked checkbox, in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874949/what-is-the-syntax-for-boolean-attributes-e-g-a-checked-checkbox-in-html)

Answer (score 27):

**HTML5 spec**:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected

> The selected attribute is a boolean attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**:

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<option selected />
<option selected="" />
<option selected="selected" />
<option selected="SeLeCtEd" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<option selected="0" />
<option selected="1" />
<option selected="false" />
<option selected="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<option />
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `selected="selected"`, since `<option selected>` is invalid XHTML (but valid HTML) and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<option selected>` as it is shorter.

Comment: dude why you did not got much votes. let me give you a mighty vote. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Correct method according to W3C will be selected = "selected" as noted here 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option

Quentin: Not duplicated because this question is related to select,option meanwhile your response is related to checkboxes

(Same answer, different order to avoid "not an answer, it's a comment" comments for those unable to read a full post

Comment: thats more a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want set selected more than 1 option in select, dont forget add to select attribute multiple and add to name of select [] else it doesnt work.

```html
<select name="mega_select[]" multiple>
  <option value="some" selected="selected">some</option>
  <option value="value" selected="selected">value</option>
  <option value="non">non</option>
</select>
```