# checkbox set to checked = false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm generating an HTML input with `checked="false"`, however the checkbox is showing up checked.

I did the following in the javascript console and can't quite figure out whats going on. The resulting HTML after using `.prop()` to set the value to false looks the same except now the checkbox is not checked on the form.

```
> $(':input[checked]').prop('checked');
< true
> $(':input[checked]')
< [
<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"caseVal" checked=​"false">​
]
> $(':input[checked]').prop('checked',false);
< [
<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"caseVal" checked=​"false">​
]
```

I'm under the impression that I should just be setting `checked="checked"` OR not including the checked property at all if its false is that best practice? Either way I'd like to know what's going on in the above code.

Comment: Include for true, leave out for false `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />` `<input type="checkbox" />`

Comment: Your example works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qSSa8/. Are you just looking at the console output, or the actual DOM rendering? Have you tried `.removeAttr()`?

Comment: if you want it unchecked then :``<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"caseVal">​``, if checked then:``<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"caseVal" checked=​"checked">​``

Comment: Check this [prop() vs attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/3639582)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for boolean attributes, e.g. a checked checkbox, in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874949/what-is-the-syntax-for-boolean-attributes-e-g-a-checked-checkbox-in-html)

Comment: `prop()` does not update the HTML, just the DOM. If you're going to inspect the HTML afterwards use `attr()` or `removeAttr()`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Don't put `checked="false"`

You only put checked="checked" for valid XHTML, otherwise you'd do

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

The browser doesn't care what value is assigned to checked attribute, as soon as it sees `checked` in the checkbox input tag, it's flagged as checked.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I'll accept this as soon as the system allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function () { $(e).prop("checked", false);}`

// "e" refers to button element

Answer (score -1):

How to Uncheck in this case, example my code is: (see below)

```
if(previousHighlightedCheckbox!=null) {
    console.log(sent.id, previousHighlightedCheckbox); // current checkbox and previous check box values are different.
    document.getElementById(previousHighlightedCheckbox).checked = false; // still this does not uncheck previous one
  }
```