# ternary code to change checkbox in template string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, lit-element

I'm working with polymer and lit-element. In the render function I have a template string as follow:

```
render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click="${this.onRemove}">Remove</button>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked="${this.todoItem.done} ? 'true' : 'false'"
          @click="${this.changeStatus}"
        />
      </li>
    `;
  }
```

I know this won't work because based on several stackoverflow answers, any value that you put `checked` equal to is going to mark it as checked.

If I do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ${this.todoItem.done} ? 'checked' : ''" @click="${this.changeStatus}"/>
```

I get an error

> TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentNode' property on 'TreeWalker':
>   The provided value is not of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the docs I found my answer: I had to use `html`
https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates. The following codes work.

```
render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click="${this.onRemove}">Remove</button>
        ${this.todoItem.done
          ? html`
              <input type="checkbox" checked @click="${this.changeStatus}" />
            `
          : html`
              <input type="checkbox" @click="${this.changeStatus}" />
            `}
      </li>
    `;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

```
render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click="${this.onRemove}">Remove</button>
        ${html`
          <input type="checkbox" ?checked="${this.todoItem.done}" @click="${this.changeStatus}" />
        `}
      </li>
    `;
  }
```

**UPDATE V2**

```
render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click="${this.onRemove}">Remove</button>
        <input type="checkbox" ?checked="${this.todoItem.done}" @click="${this.changeStatus}" />
      </li>
    `;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

your ternary codes are not running at the moment, they are enclosed by "" which are used to enclos strings. enclose the ternary code with {}. It will work.

```
{${this.todoItem.done} ? 'true' : 'false'}
```

instead of

```
"${this.todoItem.done} ? 'true' : 'false'"
```

follow this link for more detail 
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: ```<input
          type="checkbox"
          checked="{${this.todoItem.done} ? 'true' : 'false'}"
          @click="${this.changeStatus}"
        />``` didn't work

Comment: follow the link i provided, " anything script here doesnot run". { any scrpt here runs }. remove "" enclosure.

Comment: the problem with the link you provided is that is for react and react works with JSX. the return here is a string so the examples that say Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator in your link wont work.

Comment: render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click={this.onRemove}>Remove</button>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.todoItem.done ? 'true' : 'false'}
          @click=${this.changeStatus}
        />
      </li>
    `;
  }

Comment: that doesn't work keep showing the checkbox as checked wether the value is true or false. Even if I enter ```checkbox="asdfasdfads"``` it will show the checkbox as checked because that's how they work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514566/checkbox-set-to-checked-false-not-working

Comment: render() {
    this.todoItem = JSON.parse(this.todoItem);
    return html`
      <li>
        ${this.todoItem.item} <button @click={this.onRemove}>Remove</button>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.todoItem.done ? true : false}
          @click=${this.changeStatus}
        />
      </li>
    `;
  }

Comment: that still showing the checkboxes chekcked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514566/checkbox-set-to-checked-false-not-working. Thanks for your help. I got it working